# Retrieving files from CVS repository by executing windows commands line from a python script based upon the input specified by the user

Tags: python, file, command-line, subprocess, cvs

I have few command line interface command which are executable using windows command prompt.There are few commands that I have used to retrieve files from CVS repository using command prompt.Now I want to execute these commands by means of a python script.I have found out that I have to use subprocess inorder to interact with command prompt by means of a python script.I am trying to run the piece of code below to retrieve files from CVS repository by means of HEAD.When I try to execute these commands directly from command prompt they execute properly.I can see that it creates a local workspace and it retrieves files properly.But when i execute python script,it doesn't perform any action.I need your help.I also want to retrieve files by means of tag.

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess

Current_Working_Directory=os.getcwd()
print "Current_Working_Directory",Current_Working_Directory

cmd = ['cvs',
   '-d:::pserver:<username>@<computername>:<repository>
   'login']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output=p.communicate()
print "p",p
cmd1=['set','CVSROOT','=','pserver:<username>@<computername>:<repository>']
p1 = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print p1
cmd2=['cvs','co','-r','HEAD','Test']
p2 = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print p2
```

Answer (score 0):

Running `subprocess.Popen` creates a new subprocess. The `CVSROOT` envioronment variable will only exist for the brief existence of that subprocess so it will not be around for the next Popen which executes the cvs command. You want to do `os.environ["CVSROOT"] = 'pserver:<username>@<computername>:<repository>'` instead.

In fact, if you do that before the `cvs login` you shouldn't need to specify it explicitly in that command either.

The alternative is to specify the cvsroot with `-d` in the `cvs co` command as you did with the `cvs login` command.

Comment: Actually if i try to run above code.It doesn't retrieve files from CVS repository whereas if it try to run those commands on command prompt,files are extracted properly and i can see those files in my local workspace. How can I retrieve files using python script?

Comment: What have you done to debug the problem? What output is CVS giving?

Comment: I have changed my approach now.Instead of executing command line interfaces directly using python script.I have created a batch file which has all commands that retrieve files from CVS repository and i am trying to call this bat file from my python script.This worked for me!!